# Set id from sequence vs manualy insert using JPA Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, generator, sequence

I have entity where id generated using sequence

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "ENTITY_SEQ", sequenceName = "ENTITY_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ENTITY_SEQ")
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

And it work OK. But when i cretate test and set id manualy, sequence rewrite value and set it's own value. Is any posibility to change priority of setting value to ID?

Comment: The first question what crosses a mind - why do you need manual control over ID if it is unqiue one ? JPA sequence makes it unique. Technically some JPA providers allow to create the custom sequence generator (like @GenericGenerator in Hibernate) but do you really need this.?

Comment: Because i need sometimes manualy migrate some data with already existent ID. And i want be sure that all will insert correctly and will be consistent

Comment: >>i need sometimes manualy migrate some data with already existent ID. This requirement comes in conflict with autogenerated ID. Imagine you insert  1,2,3,4,5 manually, but your sequence starts with 1 - what happens ? You get unique constraint violation once you try to call persist(). OK, imagine you start sequence with 6. But "sometimes" you again add 1001,1002,1003 - well, what happens when sequence reaches 1001 ? Again - unique constraint violation. And are you going to re-create and re-compile sequence "sometimes" ?